# SP2-306 error - SQLplus

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am using the below script to run the sql files and to pass the logs to log folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
time_stamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)
mkdir -p "/APPLICATIONS/log/anonymize_${time_stamp}"

while read -r line
do
    schema_name="$line"
        error_level=0
    echo "$schema_name"

    password=$(sed -n "/name>.*$schema_name<\/name>/{s#.*<password>##;s#</password>.*##;p;}" connections.xml)
    datasource=$(sed -n "/name>.*$schema_name<\/name>/{s#.*<datasource>##;s#</datasource>.*##;p;}" connections.xml)
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF>> "/APPLICATIONS/log/anonymize_${time_stamp}/anonymize_$schema_name.log"
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
connect $schema_name/${password}@${datasource}
@/APPLICATIONS/sql/start_anon.sql
EOF

sql_return_code=$?

if [ $sql_return_code != 0 ]
then
echo "$schema_name - Failed. Logs - /APPLICATIONS/log"
echo "Error code $sql_return_code"
else
 echo "$schema_name - Success."
fi

echo "************************************"
done < "/APPLICATIONS/exe/schema.txt"
```

The below script works fine from the server as it is expected.
But If the same script is launched in this server externally from different server, it is failing with the error as

```
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | /
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

Kindly advise.

SOLVED: 
After mentioning connections.xml with the full path , the script has been executed successfully from the different servers also.

Comment: My guess is that the other server's version of sqlplus is not so forgiving regarding the case of the options. How about -S /NOLOG?

Comment: @jeff6times7 - Do I have to change it to Capital letters??

Comment: The docs show the options are specified as -S and /NOLOG. Yes, the docs indicate using -S instead of -s and so forth.

Comment: @jeff6times7 - After changing the path to connections.xml with the full path - the script works.